# Setting up fastcgi with nginx

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I am using following c code

```
#include <fcgi_stdio.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
        printf("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n");
        printf("Hello world in C\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using following command

```
 spawn-fcgi -a127.0.0.1 -p9000 -n ./a.out
```

Where  spawn-fcgi , I installed using fedora 15 repo.

Nginx config is:

```
   location / {
        root html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
```

I am getting following error:

```
2012/02/13 16:15:45 [error] 17998#0: *1 upstream closed prematurely FastCGI stdout while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /hello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:8081"
```

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue code should be

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
        printf("Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n");
        printf("Hello world in C\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```